# Dynamicaly populate object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am writing a util method, that changes the date format in an object that has known fields. it throws **undefined** when I try to generate the fields dynamically.

```
const dateFields = [
  'booking_timestamp',
  'box_timestamp',
  'createdAt',
  'updatedAt'
];
exports.convertToLondon = (arrayToProcess) => {
  console.log(arrayToProcess.booking_timestamp); // 20170421 04:30:00
  const processedArray = dateFields.map(field => {
    console.log(arrayToProcess.field); // undefined
    // const container = {};
    const utcCutoff = moment.utc(arrayToProcess.field, 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss');
    // arrayToProcess.field => i would like to variable to dynamically populate for arrayToProcess.booking_timestamp
    const displayCutoff = utcCutoff.clone().tz('Europe/London');

    console.log('utcCutoff:', utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ssa Z')); // => utcCutoff: 20170421 04:30:00pm +00:00
    console.log('displayCutoff:', displayCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss:sssZ')); // => displayCutoff: 20170421 12:30:00pm -04:00
    return null;
  });
  return processedArray;
};
```

Comment: `container` is an empty object, no data is set inside

Comment: updated the code, I talking about the line console.log(arrayToProcess.field);

Comment: I tried to help you and I think I'm right but I see you downvoted so ..... good luck :) Try to improve the description of your question this is not clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you're trying to access `arrayToProcess.field` instead of just `field` (an element of your array). You're in the `.map` callback where you have the instance of `field`. arrayToProcess.field does not exist.

And you also have to access the array that's in your function parameter (arrayToProcess) instead of the variable defined above (dateFields) that doesn't exists into the context of your function.

```
const dateFields = [
  'booking_timestamp',
  'box_timestamp',
  'createdAt',
  'updatedAt'
];
exports.convertToLondon = (arrayToProcess) => {
  console.log(arrayToProcess.booking_timestamp); // 20170421 04:30:00
  const processedArray = arrayToProcess.map(field => { // use arrayToProcess and not dateFields
    console.log(field); // use just field
    // const container = {};
    const utcCutoff = moment.utc(arrayToProcess.field, 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss');
    // arrayToProcess.field => i would like to variable to dynamically populate for arrayToProcess.booking_timestamp
    const displayCutoff = utcCutoff.clone().tz('Europe/London');

    console.log('utcCutoff:', utcCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ssa Z')); // => utcCutoff: 20170421 04:30:00pm +00:00
    console.log('displayCutoff:', displayCutoff.format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss:sssZ')); // => displayCutoff: 20170421 12:30:00pm -04:00
    return null;
  });
  return processedArray;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know if i understood your question at 100%, but i think that you want to dynamically create fields based on the input object.

In this case the solution is simple, you need to access the new field with `[]` notation and not with `.` notation:

`arrayToProcess.field` --> `arrayToProcess[field]`

Because in the first case you will try to access the field `field` on the object:

```
{
  field: 123
}
```

While in the second notation you will access the attribute named as the `field` variable value.